# Qué significa START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un proceso que hace una petición a base de datos y al terminar de procesarla vuelve a hacer la petición. Esto lo hace cíclicamente todo el tiempo y de vez en cuando me registra el siguiente error la función:

```
ERROR: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
  Where: remote SQL command: START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

Estuve buscando documentación en PostgreSQL y habla sobre ISOLATION LEVEL y describe un poco su significado pero no logro entender exactamente a qué se refiere. Cuándo es que pasa y por qué pasa?

El trabajo de mi función es conectarse a una base externa mediante foreigns tables, ejecutar un EXCEPT entre una tabla de esa base de datos foranea y una tabla mía y luego replicar cambios.

Pero, qué significa ese error?

Comment: Podrias probar reindexdb y pg_dump, parece un archivo danado o algo asi.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner más de los logs, justo antes de que se bajara el servicio?  además de la version de PostgreSQL que estas usando y si es posible el codigo que causa esa caida